# Query groupby and count separated values

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to create a table in google sheets, listing some elements (in column) and at the same time counting other elements, currently grouped in a string separated by semicolons.

The example is the following:

[initial dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15P4myWDfIWXLhVUapGUxRA3N0gPb0EpdRHRbvo3QUFs/edit#gid=0)

[desired outcome](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15P4myWDfIWXLhVUapGUxRA3N0gPb0EpdRHRbvo3QUFs/edit#gid=1379227467)

I have tried some queries but for the moment I have been able only to [count the semicolon-separated elements](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15P4myWDfIWXLhVUapGUxRA3N0gPb0EpdRHRbvo3QUFs/edit#gid=1760367474), without being able to group them for "markets".

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(source!A2:A&"×"&SPLIT(source!B2:B, ";")), "×")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"))
```

[image]